# PHP: system() method doesn't work on Windows 8.1

Tags: php, shell, cmd

I've a button in my app that sends an AJAX request to some `.php` page that execute the code:
`system('start D:/');` When I view it in Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit with XAMPP, it works just as expected, however, when I test it on Windows 8.1 64bit with WAMPP, it doesn't do anything (it doesn't even return any error). Even if I access the file directly from the URL and not via AJAX request, it simply doesn't run the CMD command (blank page as a result).

I've tried to change the code to see that maybe Windows 8.1 doesn't allow opening a specific folder, but no avail. I've also tried to enable apache to "interact with the dekstop" by going to:

`Start->run->services.msc`

However, I couldn't find `Apache` listed there (hence, couldn't set the option). I viewed `httpd.conf, httpd-ssl.conf, httpd-xampp.conf and php.ini` to see if I can find anything that relates to this problem, no success.

Any idea why in windows 8.1 it doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't ship with system in the default disable_functions list in the php.ini does it?

Comment: @PaulNorman Thanks for the reply. It seems like disable_functions is empty.